# Is it harmful to explicitly state ranges in if-then-else statements?

Tags: java, conditional-statements

(I searched for "else if range" but did not come up with any posts that answered my question).

When using if .. elseif .. else to select what to do based on a variable being in certain (mutually exclusive) ranges, I like to specify the ranges explicitly:

```
int num = 55;
String message;

if (num >= 20) {
    // update message variable
    message = "Bigger or equal to than 20";
}
else if (10 <= num && num < 20) {
    // update message variable
}
else if (0 <= num && num < 10) {
   // update message variable
}
else if (num < 0) {
   // update message variable
}

System.out.println(message);
```

But all the textbooks and lecture notes I see write such an example like this:

```
int num = 55;
String message;

if (num >= 20) {
    // update message variable
    message = "Bigger or equal to than 20";
}
else if (num >= 10) {
    // update message variable
}
else if (num >= 0) {
   // update message variable
}
else {
   // update message variable
}

System.out.println(message);
```

I understand why they make sure to use an else at the end (i.e. to prevent Java compiler from thinking that a variable like message might not get initialized, if that variable was a primitive), but given that all textbooks and lecture notes show the other style, are there any issues caused by explicitly writing out the ranges for all the other conditions, as I like to do?

Answer (score 7):

Don't repeat yourself.

With your approach, you're repeating the same value twice in the code, unnecessarily. This has several disadvantages, including:

- It makes it easier to introduce errors during maintenance, by changing one of the values, but not another.
- During execution it performs a redundant check. If you're in the `else if`, you already know the prior condition was false.
- The code is longer without adding any additional information. It takes longer to read, and longer to inspect.

Later maintenance may change one of the values, but not the other, leading to some surprising behavior.

```
if ( num >= 30 ) {
    // update message variable
}
else if (10 <= num && num < 20 ) { // Whoops! 
    // update message variable
}
...
```

You could avoid this by defining a constant for each value. But then your code is still specifying a redundant check.

```
final int HIGH = 20;
final int MEDIUM = 10;
final int LOW = 0;

if (num >= HIGH ) {
   // update message variable
}
else if (MEDIUM <= num && num < HIGH ) { // We already know num<HIGH
    // update message variable
}
...
```

Comment: How interesting; I never thought of the "later maintenance" concern.
So it seems that there are pros and cons to each approach. I wonder if there is an industry standard that can give me some authoritative guidance?

Comment: @silph "later maintenance" is always a concern in real life. In a school assignment it might not be, but it's good to start to thinking like it is.

Comment: @Andreas, but I have seen overthinking produce unmaintainable code. Thinking about later maintance often leads to ideology. Ideology leads to blindly applying patterns.

Comment: The culprit here isn't the explicitness, but the magic numbers. Magic numbers are numbers that are of importance for the code and not trivial in the context. If the magic number is used in more than one place, then it should be a constant otherwise this can and most likely will introduce inconsistencies and bugs. More importantly the meaning of a number is not apparent to future readers, thus it's advisable to use named constants, even for stuff that only comes up once.

Comment: Personally, I always put the `else if` on the same line as the `}`, to highlight the fact that this is a continuation of the same `if` statement. Without that, the code *structure* is not clear on a cursory scan of the code.

Comment: @silph - Helpful principles include parsimony, elegance and DRY. Execute only what is necessary. Express only what is necessary. Avoid repeating yourself. See also Antoine de Saint-Exupéry's quote: *"perfection is finally attained not when there is no longer anything to add, but when there is no longer anything to take away."*

Comment: Upvoted. It's always a hazard answering borderline opinion based questions, but you make some good points here. Epitomises the fact that every line of code needs careful consideration.

Comment: How can I improve this question so it's no longer on hold? I see that there are many opinions. Does this mean my question is a stupid question and therefore it doesn't matter which style I use, since it's "just a matter of opinion" and that specific expertise has nothing to say about this issue?

Comment: @silph - It absolutely does *not* mean it's a stupid question. It merely means that this site strives to stick to questions that can be answered with facts, and to avoid squabbles. Sometimes people can be a little too quick to close questions. Sometimes a keyword like "style" can lead to closing, despite the presence of a real, answerable question. If it were me, I would ask if your approach were *harmful*, rather than asking if it were incorrect or bad style.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm building some code that will run on some kind of vehicle to be landed successfully on another planet then I'd always plump for *clarity*. Remember that a line of code will be written *once* but could be read hundreds of times. Your first snippet will be far easier to understand during a 4am debugging session.

Your first way is indeed much clearer and bugs will not be introduced if an errant refactorer reorders the conditional checks.

I'd always finish with an `} else {` though, ideally with some kind of assertion if program control ought not reach that.

Comment: I disagree with the refactoring part: The first version is also very prone to refactoring errors because you have to make sure that the upper limit of each range is exactly the lower limit of the next one.

Comment: I think the concern raised in [answer by Andy Thomas](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40183548/5221149) is a more realistic concern than someone rearranging an if-elseif-elseif sequence of statements. Anything dumb enough to rearranging that kind of construct without realizing that `else` depends on `if` should be fired.